# How does ForeFront UAG implement single sign-on?

Tags: single-sign-on, microsoft-forefront, microsoft-forefront-2010

One feature of Forefront is the ability to pre-authenticate external users before their requests are sent to a published web application.  In addition, it is supposed to be able to forward the accepted credentials to the web application (according to [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd857314.aspx)).  How specifically are these credentials passed?  Are they in a header?  Are they sent with every request, or just the first?